# restoring mySQL backup files, onto different server (with different name)

Tags: mysql

I have a backup of all SQL files taken from one host. Now as the account name for the FTP/CPANEL was different the, prefix of SQL files contains this name. Now to restore these to another server is that possible along with all the corresponding username and passwords regarding the databases created from the old server?

Answer (score 0):

it won't be possible. You should give the cpanel zip to your provider to import it via cPanel/WHM on the new server, then you will have the same user/files as on your old host.